# Display a line outside the axis limits in Octave

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I'd like to draw a line that extends beyond the limits of the axis. I've tried setting the `clipping` property to `off` like this:

```
figure
axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
hold on
set(gca,'outerPosition',[0, 0.5, 1, 0.5])
lh = line([2, 8],[8, -5]);
set(lh, 'clipping', 'off') 
print('line_plot.png')
```

I get a figure that looks like this:

[image: plot with line that ends at the border of the axis]

Is there a way to make the line extend beyond the x-axis? I'm using gnuplot and AquaTerm. Would this be possible in another terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gnuplot, I would recommend annotating an arrow, which can extend beyond the axis. Here's a minimal example to achieve what you outline in your question:

```
# define the location of your plot:
bm = 0.15
lm = 0.12
rm = 0.95
tm = 0.95 
set lmargin at screen lm
set rmargin at screen rm
set bmargin at screen bm
set tmargin at screen tm  

# define your axis limits:
xmax = 10.0             
xmin = 0.0
ymax = 10.0                 
ymin = 0.0                  
set xrange [xmin:xmax]
set yrange [ymin:ymax]

# define you data points:
xstart = 2
ystart = 8
xend = 8
yend = -5

# convert points into screen coordinates:
dx_rel = (rm-lm)/(xmax-xmin)
dy_rel = (tm-bm)/(ymax-ymin)

xstart_rel = lm + dx_rel * xstart
ystart_rel = bm + dy_rel * ystart
xend_rel = lm + dx_rel * xend                                          
yend_rel = bm + dy_rel * yend  

# define 'arrow' without head in screen coordinates:
set arrow 1 from screen xstart_rel,ystart_rel \
              to screen xend_rel,yend_rel nohead  

# plot will not show when empty, include dummy plot command:
set parametric 
plot xstart, ystart not
```

The [`clip` option](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node165.html) you refer to in gnuplot does not allow you to extend your plot past the axis. It is meant to remove data points close to the axis to avoid symbols overlaying with those axis.
The [`arrow`](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-15800043.2), however, can be specified in [`screen`](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-4900010) coordinates (the *screen* in this case is the plot window) which allows you to draw outside the axis.
To match specific data-coordinates, you have to translate those into screen-coordinates. This will only work reliably when you define you plot boundaries in those screen coordinates. That way, you can calculate where each data point will be on the screen.
When `set`ing the `arrow`, make sure to use `screen` before the coordinates to indicate the right coordinate system.
The script above will give you this plot:

[image]